# Java program about (" ")'s importance

Tags: java

As you can see in the code comment below, I am wondering about the  " "'s importance in the program below. I tried to run the program without
 " "and the count still stayed at 0 so it seems that " " seems pretty important. I thought ""'s function was putting space between string. What is it doing here? Thank you so much!

```
package js01;

import java.util.Scanner;

//search 1 
//user input of an alphabet and a sentence, return a count of that alphabet
public class J0306_search {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String str1;
         String ch;
         //must be a string type although the input will be a chracter because the user input is taken as a string 
         int count=0;
         int i;

         Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.println("enter a sentence");
         str1=s.nextLine();
         System.out.println("enter an alphabet that u would like to count");
         ch=s.next();

         for (i=0;i<str1.length();i++) {

             if (ch.equals(""+str1.charAt(i))) {

                 //why is "" needed?
                 //
                 count++;
             }
         }
         System.out.println("count is:"+count);
         s.close();
     }

}
```

Comment: Your code is using an empty string (`""`), not a string with space (`" "`) like you used in the title and your question text.

Answer (score 3):

> why is "" needed?

`str1.charAt(i)` returns a `char`. `ch` is a `String`. If you use `equals` on a `String` and pass in a `char`, it gets autoboxed as a `Character` and `equals` always returns false when the types are different (in a properly-written `equals`).

`""+str1.charAt(i)` creates a string so that you're passing a `String` to `equals`, so it compares the two strings to see if they have the same characters in them. (Another way is `String.valueOf(str1.charAt(i))`, which looks longer but produces more efficient bytecode — although the JIT may optimize it if it's in a hotspot.)

Comment: Thank you! I understand now!

Answer (score 2):

It converts your `str1.charAt(i)` to string so it's an alternative for `Character.toString(str1.charAt(i))`

Comment: "...so it's a alternative for .toString()" no since `char` is primitive type so it doesn't have *any* methods, not even `toString()` so it can't be its alternative.

Comment: I'm not a java geek but AFAIK `.toString` is available to char ```char c='S';  
String s=String.valueOf(c); ``` is possible I guess?

Comment: In your example you never used `toString` so I am not sure what you mean by ".toString is available" . Your example uses `String.valueOf` which is *entirely different method*. Fact that primitive types like `char` don't have methods including `toString` is main reason `String.valueOf` method was created.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clearify please take back your downvote @Pshemo

Comment: Thanks for correction and opportunity to retrace my vote.